# Saving WMS getFeatureInfo points to layer

Tags: qgis, wms, query, fields-attributes

I have imported a vector layer from a WMS server into QGIS. I am able to query the objects on this layer with the Identify tool and get (most of the time) information about that object.

I have another (local) layer of points that I've created. I would like to automate that query process such that a new attribute is created in the point layer from a query to the WMS at that point.

I can't find any information on this, but if the data is made available to the Identify tool my logic tells me that this should be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your case correctly (I could not understand the data flow direction). However one keyword that might be useful is WFS (Web Feature Service). If you want to update/modify an underlying data set of a WMS you will probably end up with WFS (or even WFS-T).